# No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'string' en 'int'

Tags: c#

quisiera saber si alguien me ayuda con el siguiente error, en visual studio 2013, estoy creando un simple crud del nombre y edad de una persona en WPF, al momento de referenciar los valores de la tabla 'person' en este caso 'Age', me sale el siguiente error: No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'string' en 'int'.
Todo eso ocurre en la linea del Age = d.Age,
A que se deberá dicho problema?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace CRUD_TAREA
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Lógica de interacción para MenuYLista.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MenuYLista : Page
    {
        public MenuYLista()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Refresh()
        {
            List<PersonViewModel> lst = new List<PersonViewModel>();
            using(Model.WPFCRUDTAREAEntities db=new Model.WPFCRUDTAREAEntities())
            {
                lst = (from d in db.person
                       select new PersonViewModel
                       {
                           Name = d.Name,
                           Age = d.Age,
                           Id = d.Id
                       }).ToList();
            }
        }
    }

    public class PersonViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Comment: que es lo que no entendes.. el error? el problema? porque tenes que hacer la conversion? porque no la hace sola?

Comment: @gbianchi entonces que stackoverflow deje poner código que no lo impida, siempre cuando trato de poner código me lo impide, y lo segundo, no se porque me lanza que Age sea un valor string, si ya esta definido como int, eso es lo que quiero solucionar, el problema en si.

Comment: que codigo te impide poner tu codigo como texto? ahora agrego una respuesta, pero si arreglas tu pregunta mejor...

Comment: ah no para.. que tiene db.person?

Comment: @gbianchi person es la tabla de la base de datos, contiene los valores de Name, Age e Id

Comment: no. person es una clase en tu sistema. que tiene? y en algun lado, Age esta definido como string.

Comment: Me late que db.person tiene Age como String

Answer (score 2):

Probablemente d.Age ha llegado como string y según tu clase lo espera int.

prueba esto:

```
lst = (from d in db.person select new PersonViewModel{
            Name = d.Name,
            Age = int.Parse(d.Age),
            Id = d.Id`introducir el código aquí
       }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

El error te sucede porque el objeto que llamas d, tiene un campo Age que es un entero al que estas pasando una cadena(string),como espera un entero y le pasas un string te da un error de tipos, la solución está en cambiar el tipo string a un int, yo conozco 3 maneras de hacerlo.

estas dos siguientes pueden producir una excepcion si no se consigue hacer el casteo(transformación entre tipos)  entre string e int

```
Age = int.Parte(d.Age);
Age = Convert.ToInt16(d.Age);
```

esta forma de castear me parece la más adecuada, devuelve en la variable resultado el resultado del casteo puedes comprobar si esta operación ha sido posible mediante el booleano b , y d.Age es la cadena que vamos a convertir

```
int resultado;
bool b = int.TryParse(d.Age,out resultado);
```

Entonces podría quedar así:

```
lst = (from d in db.person
                       select new PersonViewModel
                       {
                           Name = d.Name,
                           Age = Convert.ToInt16(d.Age)//cast goes here,
                           Id = d.Id
                       }).ToList();
```